# data not coming from ItemsSource

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

this is where I am trying to populate items in xaml

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EventsList}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

this is a dummy method in view model, that I have Binded

```
public string[] EventsList()
        {
            string[] values = {"event1", "event2"};
            return values;
        }
```

but this isn't giving any output. also this method is not being called as well.

Comment: you have to assign the ItemSource i.e. EventsList. Can you post the code of you .cs file ?

Comment: @Ajay i've assigned it already. see the xaml,  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EventsList}">

Comment: you have to bind it from code like itemControl.ItemsSource  = EventsList;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because you are trying to bind to a method. You can only bind to properties.

```
public string[] EventsList
{
    get
    {
        string[] values = {"event1", "event2"};
        return values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many issues here.

The first one is that you can't bind to a method. You can bind only to a property.

The second one is that you're binding the TextBlock to the `Value` of your object, which is supposed to be a string. A string has no `Value` property.

Try this instead:

```
public string[] EventsList
{
    get
    {
        string[] values = {"event1", "event2"};
        return values;
    }
}
```

Then bind to this property and display the full string object (by using `{Binding}`)

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EventsList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Note: it supposes that the class in which you're declaring the `EventList` property has been assigned to the `DataContext` property of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MainPage.xaml
      <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
            <StackPanel>
                <ItemsControl Name="itemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding EventsList}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        this.itemControl.ItemSource = EventsList();
    }
```

Comment: Assigning the ItemSource from the code-behind is fine, but then you should remove the `ItemsSource="{Binding EventsList}"` part from the XAML

Comment: its perfectly correct & more elegant to assign itemssource from xaml. the issue was pointed out in other answer. thanks

Comment: @KooKiz Ok. It works when I remove ItemsSource="{Binding EventsList}".